# Phrasal verbs confusion

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, phrasal-verbs, direct-objects, ditransitive-verbs

I saw the following sentences on the cambridge online site.I made some changes and I want to know if they are applicable ?

1- They are digging up the potatoes.
(Original)

2- A detective to dig up information about the employee. (Original)

3- They are digging potatoes up.(Edited from 1)

4- A detective to dig information about the employee. (Edited from 2)

Comment: Can you provide the exact source for #2?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence 3 is a totally commonplace / acceptable variant of sentence 1.

Sentences 2 and 4 are a more complicated case.  I am not actually convinced sentence 2 is a sentence, which means it is rather odd to encounter it from a reputable TEFL source.  It appears to me a sentence fragment.  Perhaps somebody else can think of another reading whereby it is a fully-fledged sentence in its own right, but at the moment I can't.

Your sentence 4 has the same property, but this is obviously not your "fault" since it is like that in the original sentence.

However, the other change you make by removing "up" is a problematic one.  To dig something is, idiomatically, to enjoy it or condone it.  The phrase is strongly associated with hippies and counterculture of the 60s/70s ("Can you dig it?"), but still in occasional use today.  Although the context makes it plain that this meaning it not intended - a detective would not be sitting around going "this is great info about the employee, I dig it", unless that detective was [Shaft](https://youtu.be/Q429AOpL_ds?t=182) - it still makes the sentence somewhat awkward, and essentially forces the listener to complete the "dig up" idiom by mentally adding the "up".

Comment: "...which means it is rather odd to encounter it from a reputable TEFL source."  Indeed, but the OP didn't link to the original source (even though it is apparently online) so we can't be certain that it hasn't been accidentally altered.